# What is the best way to compile a specific C program that may have dependencies?

Tags: c, embedded

I would like to compile the following C file on an embedded platform:

https://github.com/openwsn-berkeley/openwsn-fw/blob/develop/firmware/openos/bsp/chips/at86rf231/radio.c

However, as you can see, on lines 20-26 of radio.c it references "radiotimer_capture_cbt":

```
typedef struct {
   radiotimer_capture_cbt startFrame_cb;
   radiotimer_capture_cbt endFrame_cb;
   radio_state_t state;
} radio_vars_t;

radio_vars_t radio_vars;
```

So now I need to hunt down where it is defined and make sure I include the right header.

I have cloned the entire GIT repository here: https://github.com/openwsn-berkeley/openwsn-fw, and I'm looking for a way to compile this easily.

Is there a better way to get this compiled other than going through the brutal dependency nightmare?

My ultimate goal is only to get radio.c compiled and anything it needs. I do not see any makefiles in this project so I'm expecting they want us to use an IDE.

Comment: It uses scons rather than makefiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project seems to use scons as a build system. So the simplest way is to dive into the scons files.

There's a small scons file in the directory containing the linked file and two main script in the top directory.

But if you want to play, first remove headers include, try to compile (using -c) to know which one are really needed. Once you get an object file (.o) you can use nm to identify missing symbols (marked with U.) Good luck …